# Find specific item in list faster

Tags: c#, performance

I have a text file that contains 8.14 million rows. I'm trying to find all rows that contains specific words. There is a `******` section in the code below. It takes 1.07 seconds on that section. This speed is so slow that I would like to find the fastest way possible.

How can I do it the fastest?

```
// The Random.txt file contains 8.14 million items of the below format.  
// format = [groupnumber],[name],[num1],[num2],[num3],[num4],[num5],[num6]    

// group1,car,1,22,37,39,42,45  
// group2,fruit,1,12,13,14,22,36  
// group3,robot,4,6,9,31,32,34  
// group4,cat,11,12,17,19,42,45  
// group5,dog,40,41,42,43,44,45  
// ...
// ...

// load file to list group1  
var group1 = File.ReadLines("Random.txt", Encoding.Default).ToList();  

*****************************************************************************************  
//I want this section to be faster
Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
w .Start();  

// Find items in group1 that contain all 4,6,9,31,32 in num area  
var group2 = group1.AsParallel().Select(x => x + ",").Where(x => x.Contains(",4,")  
                                                && x.Contains(",6,")  
                                                && x.Contains(",9,")  
                                                && x.Contains(",31,")  
                                                && x.Contains(",32,"))  
                                    .Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.Length - 1)).ToList();  
w .Stop();
//Elapsed Time : 00:00:01.0722169  
//I want this section to be faster
******************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Are you talking about a static data, many times execution scenario, or about changing data / one time execution?

Comment: What makes you think filtering 8 millions row in less than a second is possible ?

Comment: 8.14 **million** and **one** second? Why do you need to make that even faster? But you could possibly make it faster by using `Parallel.ForEach` and not LINQ so some lambda calls can be omitted (function calls are a bit of overhead)

Comment: why do you need `Select(x => x + ",")` before the Where?

Comment: @Natrium I guess to catch the case where the string ends with one of the numbers they are searching for, but without a trailing comma.

Comment: What is your budget? (Buy a faster computer, buy a lot of faster computers, buy a lab to invent a faster computer).

Comment: Low hanging fruit: Do some of those numbers occur less frequently than the others? If so, move the tests for those values before the more commonly occurring values.

Comment: I don't see why one would use `File.ReadLines()` and then call `ToList()` right after, since this defeats the purpose of `File.ReadLines()`. If you don't need the results *immediately*, you can iterate the output of `File.ReadLines()` properly and `yield return` the results. If you're using these results somewhere else, the enumeration may be already finished when the data is actually used (but you can enumerate the results anyway). So, the time this *section* uses is almost `0`.

Comment: @grek40 It repeats for a certain number of times and list group1 changes during the iteration.

Comment: Well, unless you have other constraints, always remember to ask yourself the question [is it worth the time?](https://xkcd.com/1205/) You don't save if you program for an hour to go from a second to 0.1 seconds for a rarely used task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can save you 2 selects:

```
    var group2 = group1.AsParallel().Where(temp => {
                                                var x = temp + ",";
                                                return x.Contains(",4,")  
                                            && x.Contains(",6,")  
                                            && x.Contains(",9,")  
                                            && x.Contains(",31,")  
                                            && x.Contains(",32,");}
                                );
```

Comment: Thank you for letting us know what's wrong. There is a significant increase in speed.
00:00:01.0722169 → 00:00:00.0002653

Comment: @sera  If you don't call `.ToList()`, you have a ParallelQuery, which is, per se, an `IEnumerable`. So you're not *materializing* the query results. I described it in a comment I posted.

Comment: @Jimi Jimi I'm sorry your opinion is correct. The key to the problem was that. I just noticed that removing .ToList () is faster. Everyone gave me the right teaching. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sera I hope you only removed the `ToList` after the `ReadLines` and not the `ToList` of your measurement...